# Is this Circuit Valid?

Tags: led, resistors, circuit-design

Thanks to the help I've received on here the last few days I have been able to put together a schematic for a project I am planning.

The project itself is lighting up a 1/400 scale model of the Cunard Queen Mary 2.

[image]

I will be running this from a 3amp 12v power source using a range of mostly 3mm LEDs along with some 0402SMDs. They will mostly be in series chains of 2 or 3, with each chain having its own direct connection. I've grouped the LEDs into like for like, so no chain is made up using different colours or types/makes.

I've broken this all up into 5 layers, depending on where the lighting sits within the model vertically.

Below are 6 images. The first 5 are each layer individually, with the final one a combination of all 5. (Please Note: There may look like there are some broken or random wires, there isn't that is just me making crude use of the software to create an outline of the model)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(The software states I will require 1.89A but my calculations come closer to 2.5A)

Should I fit a fuse? If so, what value?

I'd appreciate any input, but please keep in mind my knowledge is absolute minimum, especially where terminology is concerned, thanks.

*Edit: I've corrected the resistor value on the single red LED on layer 3, to 560ohm.*

Comment: Beware that different LEDs have different voltage drops. You may need a different resistor value for a chain of red LEDs than for a chain of white LEDs. Moreover, I’d suggest you use chains as long as possible (probably 3 for white LEDs, perhaps 4 or even 5 for yellow or red ones), to reduce the power loss in resistors.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've already taken into account the differences in drops, Almost all of the LEDs I will be using come from the same seller, and their information regarding the different ones are here:

[link](http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=152555238306&t=1505420889000&tid=310&category=181880&seller=phi-sigma-electronics&excSoj=1&excTrk=1&lsite=3&ittenable=false&domain=ebay.co.uk&descgauge=1&cspheader=1&oneClk=1&secureDesc=0)

Comment: The only exception to this are the white ones in Layer 3 (shown external to the ship). I've used the LED series parallel array wizard to find out what value resistors I need, and have selected the closes higher value I have been able to find, again from the same seller.

Fingers crossed I've taken into account everything correctly.

Regarding grouping into longer chains, I've no way of being able to calculate the resistors I'd need, as that wizard always defaults to 3 or less. And I am damn useless at math lol

Comment: No idea what wizard you’re talking about, but does it allow you to specify the forward voltage of the LED you use? It’s surprising in layer 3 that you have the same resistor value for a single red LED and for a single green one.

Comment: According to the information from the seller, the red LED has a forward voltage of 1.8v-2.2v where as the green is 3.2v-3.8v, as shown by the link I posted previously.

This is the [link](http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz) wizard I used, and yes it does.

Comment: Ahh I've just realised my error, I will correct that, thanks.

Comment: Sigh... you can at least post a pic of the dang ship.

Comment: It's not built yet LOL.

I'll add a photo to my OP.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you'd fit a fuse is to protect the wiring.

You state that you'll be running this from a 3A 12v power source. If the source is current limited, and cannot deliver more than 3A, then as long as your wiring will handle 3A, so at least 0.3 \$mm^2\$, then there's no need for a fuse.

If you substitute a car battery for your PSU, then you should fit a fuse.

Comment: It is limited. Basically a mains 12v adaptor @ 3amps

Answer (score 0):

I think a more clever design for lighting on this is to replace the wires with optical fibre and choose emitters for each level or zone you wish to control intensity of. Choose the aperture size of fibre to suit your scale.

This requires using optically clear epoxy ( like that used in 5mm LEDs)  to create an adapter or manifold to capture the light from a large area LED chip and neatly routing the optics.  I would choose the warmest LED to simulate tungsten bulbs.

Designing it so the LED is replaceable requires mechanical-optical skills than you can hone from web-searching. I expect about 10 sq.cm./watt heatsink if it has convection flow and a few watts is then all you need if your losses are minimized.  Voltage options are wide ranging on large area chips, so match Voltage to power source and use an active current limiter for dimming.

Glass fibre is better but plastic is cheaper.  For the easiest solution , get a fibre-optic lamp and change the LEDs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The white LEDs shown in the centre of layer 3 and all of the white ones in layers 4 and 5 will all be fibre optic drivers.

I couldn't possibly have done this with just LEDs alone, the count would have been near a 1000, and would have to be absolutely tiny ones.

A lot of the fibre optics I will be using are 0.25mm, with the rest made up of 0.75mm - 2.00mm. They will be used to simulate the balcony cabin porch lamps, pool lighting, flood lights for the name on the side of the smoke stack, and so on.

Comment: Do you have a schematic and BOM?  I have written many times how to compute series R for arrays based on p/n and Pd, Vf of each LED  ( more accurate than your wizard)

Comment: Say what now?

Perhaps you missed the part of my post where I said "I'd appreciate any input, but please keep in mind my knowledge is absolute minimum, especially where terminology is concerned, thanks." LOL

I understood R (resistor) and Vf (forward voltage) but the rest...not a clue lol

Comment: @DominicJamesSibthorp BOM = bill of materials (parts list), p/n = part number, Pd = power dissipation.

Comment: I dont see a schematic or bill of material (BOM) i.e. part numbers)

Comment: Right got you. I don't know where to find that information. I am buying the LEDs/Resistors from a UK seller on a well known auction site.

Comment: Did you buy your schematic too?  place links and sketch of schematic

Comment: Excuse me, no I made those schematics myself, using my very very limited knowledge of electrical drawing, and electrical engineering. OK, they might not be up to the industry accepted standard, (Please see the section in my OP that states: "...but please keep in mind my knowledge is absolute minimum, especially where terminology is concerned, thanks.").

I am still puzzled by your comment stating you don't see a schematic. There are 6 in my OP. (See above regarding them not being up to standard).

Comment: Photos look good, but I didn't zoom  (arg)

Comment: No problem. As above I know they aren't exactly as they should be, but they are as close as I can get without forking out £100's on software I am only likely to use once.

Comment: [link](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Ultra-Bright-LEDs-3mm-5mm-10mm-Red-Blue-White-Green-Yellow-Pink-UV-Warm-White-/290736745166?var=&hash=item8963204ef4)

<<< This is the listing for the LEDs I am planning on using. It's a multi listing. Mostly I will be using 3mm. Although am currently debating to revise slightly)

Assuming I am not going to get roasted for posting a link like that?

Comment: Normally 5 * 2.2V per Red/Yellow +If*Rs=12V  and 3*3.2V+If*Rs=12V per White/blue  so choose V_drop for Rs <3V not 6V or what you have. This will reduce your overall current 50%. Vspice is a free schematic editor

Comment: Thanks. I can see where my schematics are confusing you. There are no Yellow LEDs used at all. They are meant to be warm white I set them at yellow so it was recognisable to me. (Again limitations of the software) I'll annotate my images to make that clearer.

Comment: use 3 White per string + R . You are far better off getting good LEDs 10 per quid.  https://www.mouser.co.uk/Optoelectronics/LED-Emitters/Standard-LEDs-Through-Hole/_/N-ec21l?P=1z0yrkuZ1z0ysu0&Rl=ec21lZgjdh0aZ1z0t3ghZ1z0iwulSGT&Ns=Pricing%7c0  choose angle, colour, Iv mcd > 1000 etc then you can use <10mA  Same with Digikey.. use the filters